# Comprobar si dato a actualizar en BD mysql ha sido actualizado por otro usuario

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda y es que en un aplicación web de facturación donde varios usuarios pueden operar al mismo tiempo y puede generar una inconsistencia en los datos al crear nuevas facturas.

Usuario 1: crea una factura en tabla facturas_cab y sus lineas en facturas_lin, en facturas_cab existe un id autoincrementable, y ese id tiene que ser usado en la tabla facturas_lin como clave foranea.

Usuario 2:crea una factura en tabla facturas_cab y sus lineas en facturas_lin, es se realiza justo cuando el usuario uno esta creando su factura, por lo que puede dar la situación de que el id de facturas_cab incremente antes de que el Usuario 1 termine la operación de insercción de lineas de facturas.

¿como puedo comprobar que el id de la insercción que hizo el Usuario 1 no ha sido incrementado antes de que haga las insercciones de las lineas de factura?

Se que es un problema un tanto enrevesado, aún así espero que alguien lucido me ilumine.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega un poco de código, por ejemplo, cómo insertas la factura y obtienes el número para usar en líneas.

Comment: La pregunta parece basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, por que simplemente no creas una tabla LOG, y por cada acción que haga cada usuario almacenas el id del usuario y una descripción de la acción que realizo el mismo, por EJ: EL usuario 1 creo el item "Pan" con el id "1", eso lo registras en el log y después llega el usuario 2 y la cambia el nombre al item "Pan" a "Leche" y mantiene el ID 1 así sabes a que producto te relacionas y que usuario realizó el cambio, almacenas un datetime para saber cuando se realizaron las acciones y en tu sistema controlas los usuarios con éste log.

Comment: Un ejemplo en código mejoraría la calidad de tu aporte

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero el problema no tiene nada que ver con lo que comentas, el problema es que si un usuario A inserta una cabecera y usuario B inserta una cabecera (no conozco los usuarios que lo hacen, pueden ser decenas) cuando el usuario A va a introducir las lineas (que se insertan justo despues de hacer el insert de la cabecera) resulta que un usuario B a insertado ya una Cabecera, el ID autoincrement a cambiado y ya no puedo recuperar al lastID o lo puedo hacer pero este no seria el correcto.